# chrome dev tools: frame view is missing from timeline

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

There used to an option to switch between events, frames and memory view in the Chrome Dev tools timeline.

Now, there is only the events view :(

My Dev tools:

[image: missing frames view]

Dev tools documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get frame-by frame information:

1.Make sure 'flame chart view' is active
2. Click on one of the gray frames to get specific information on that frame

[image: frame view in chrome timeline]

Answer (score 5):

The old frames UX was removed. Now there is a single view provided for the Timeline. Frames are now presented as 'FPS' in the current overview area. Trouble frames are marked with a red tick both at the top of that view and on the frame itself.

Unlike the old UX however, the new frames is "higher is more FPS". So instead of looking for tall bars, you should look for short ones. The red ticks point out the major frame areas to look out for.

The official DevTools docs are currently being updated to reflect the new major shift in user experience.

[image: new_frames_view]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. where did you get this information?

Comment: What information? That the UX is updated or that the docs are being updated?

Comment: The docs. I really need the most updated, in depth docs on this as possible. Some of the data seems to be available almost at random. For example, the green image decode bars sometimes describe the image being decoded, sometimes not.

Comment: There is a WebFundamentals repository on GitHub. That is where the docs are. An issue is filled there for tracking the update. I'm also bugging the writer weekly to get it done. As far as what you need understanding about, try to make a minimal reproduction case and ask a question about it. That may be more useful than waiting and hoping the doc update covers it well.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `frame view` is actually visible.

In the example below, memory and frame window are so close to each other that looks like you `frame view` disappeared.

Just simply try to expand it by dragging the `frame view` window borders (A and B in image below).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this information helped me find where the frame-by frame information is now located. The key is that 'flame chart view' must be active, as you have pointed out in the image.